# How can I delay the need to specify T in my Asp.net user control?

Tags: c#, asp.net, vb.net, generics, user-controls

My dilemma:

- I have a POCO: "ReportSource" that is generic.
- I have a user control wrapping up some report building logic.
- My user control defines a ReportSource property but it will ultimately be the job of the page that calls the user control to assign that ReportSource property.

How can I define the property in my user control without specifying a T? Btw, I tried (just for larks) to make the user control generic... That ended badly.

```
public ReportSource<T> ReportSource {get; set;}
```

(Note that I've tagged this as C# and VB.net... C# is my norm, but I'm having to deal w/ legacy... An answer in either is appreciated)

Comment: Do all ReportSource classes implement the same interface? Can you just have a property `public Type ReportSourceType { get; set; }` and create your `ReportSource<T>` from that type in your `UserControl`?

Comment: I'm trying a variation of this now...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Could you move the `T` specific logic inside a non-generic `ReportSource`? This "delays" the need to specify T until the caller needs `T` specifically or until `ReportSource` needs `T`. In other words, `ReportSource` will have generic methods taking `T` or would otherwise encapsulate or hide `T` altogether.

Comment: Yeah, that's kind of where my mind originally went... I'm trying to reference interfaces to @driis point

Answer (score 1):

If your control doesn't know T, then it can't take advantage of it.

Perhaps you could get around by declaring a non-generic interface for `ReportSource<T>`, that includes the parts that your control needs to take advantage of ?